# $H_1(X,X-N,\mathbb Z_2)=\mathbb Z_2$, proof?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Given $X$ a connected manifold, and $N$ a connected codimension-1 submanifold. Can someone help me show how the result of the title holds?

I tried excision. That is, I tried removing $U^c-N$ where $U$ is a trivial neighbourhood about a point in $N$, but ended up with the pair $(U\cup N, U-N)$. So I can't get anywhere. The idea is to reduce the question to computing it for $(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^n\setminus\mathbb R^{n-1})$ with mod 2 coefficients. For this pair it's clearly $\mathbb Z_2$ by the long exact sequence for the pair.

So I want to know how to reduce it or know a better method. Thanks!

Comment: For those who saw the question before this edit: I added the requirement that $N$ is connected too.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the easiest way to go around it and I'd be very happy to see a more elementary solution, but I'm sharing this since it is natural from the point of view of Thom spaces (and also proves a stronger result). Note that you cannot really hope for a "three-line proof" in the topological case, since your statement implies the [separation theorem for circles in the plane](http://www.informatik.hu-berlin.de/forschung/gebiete/algorithmenII/mitarbeiter/beyersdorff/Papers/jordan.pdf).

I assume some regularity assumptions that provide the existence of a [tubular neighbourhood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood)$N \subseteq U \simeq N _{X/N}$ , for example it's enough to assume that $X, N$ are smooth and $N \hookrightarrow X$ is an embedding. By excision, we have

$H_{i}(X, X \setminus N) \simeq H_{i}(U, U \setminus N) \simeq H_{i}(N _{X/N}, N_{X/N} \setminus N) \simeq H_{i}(DN _{X/N}, DN _{X/N} \setminus N)$,

where $DN _{X/N}$ is the associated unit disk bundle. If $SN _{X/N}$ is the associated unit sphere bundle, then $(DN _{X/N}, SN _{X/N}) \rightarrow (DN _{X/N}, DN _{X/N} \setminus N)$ is a homotopy equivalence of pairs by radial retraction. Now, the inclusion $SN _{X/N} \hookrightarrow DN _{X/N}$ is a cofibration and so we have

$H_{i}(DN _{X/N}, SN_{X/N}) \simeq \tilde{H}_{i}(DN_{X/X} / SN_{X/N})$,

where $TN _{X/N} = DN_{X/N} / SN_{X/N}$ is by definition the [Thom space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thom_space) of the normal bundle. Since you're working over $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, every bundle is orientable and the Thom isomorphism theorem applies to tell us that

$H^{i}(N) \simeq \tilde{H}^{i+1}(TN _{X/N})$,

which immediately implies your statement, since $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is a field and so homology and cohomology are dual.

Comment: Thanks for a new viewpoint! I got it by Alexander Duality.